# How to get user activation URL in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

for the following code:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'my_user_register', 10, 1 );
function my_user_register($user_id){
   // how do i get user activation url
   // todo: send user an activation email
}
```

I want to send an activation email to user, but I don't know how to get the activation url. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

you can send email activation link like this.

```
global $theme_settings;
$hidDiv="none";
$login_page_url = get_permalink($theme_settings['userlogin_page']);
$home_url = get_option('siteurl');;

$firstname         =  sanitize_text_field($_POST['firstname']);
$username         =  sanitize_text_field($_POST['email']);
$password         =  sanitize_text_field($_POST['password']);
$email            =  sanitize_text_field($_POST['email']);
$lastname         =  $_POST['lastname'];        
$company          =  $_POST['company'];
$city             =  $_POST['city'];
$state            =  $_POST['state'];       
$zipcode          =  $_POST['zipcode'];
$mailemail       = $_POST['mailingaddress'];

$user_id          =  wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email );
if ( is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
    $error_string = $user_id->get_error_message();
}else
{
    theme_user_register($user_id);
    $thanks_msg_page_url = get_permalink($theme_settings['userthanks_page']);
    $trackcode = get_user_meta($user_id, 'p_user_registration_code', true);
    $site_name = get_option('blogname');
    $track_url = get_option('siteurl').'/confirmation?trackid='.$user_id.'&trackcode='.$trackcode;          
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    $headers .= "From: $site_name < $from >" . "\r\n";  
    $message = "<p> Hello ".$username;
    $message.="<p>Thank you for registering with us. Please click on the below link or copy and paste to the browser to activate your account.</p>";
    $message.="<p> $track_url</p><br>Best Regards,<br>Support Team";// Need to change this
    $from = get_option('admin_email');
    $site_name = get_option('blogname');

    wp_mail($email, 'Registration Confirmation', $message, $headers,'');
    $thanks_msg_page_url = get_permalink(theme_settings['userthanks_page']);
    wp_redirect($thanks_msg_page_url);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand why you want to get activation URL through coding, unless of course if you want to customize the default new user notification email sent by WordPress.

If you simply want to customize the Notification Email sent to the New User upon successful User Registration then you should use Filters `wp_new_user_notification_email` - customise email sent to User and/or `wp_new_user_notification_email_admin` - customise email sent to Admin.

Both these functions are in "wp-includes/pluggable.php". The filter definitions are as follows...

```
/**
         * Filters the contents of the new user notification email sent to the site admin.
         *
         * @since 4.9.0
         *
         * @param array   $wp_new_user_notification_email {
         *     Used to build wp_mail().
         *
         *     @type string $to      The intended recipient - site admin email address.
         *     @type string $subject The subject of the email.
         *     @type string $message The body of the email.
         *     @type string $headers The headers of the email.
         * }
         * @param WP_User $user     User object for new user.
         * @param string  $blogname The site title.
         */
        $wp_new_user_notification_email_admin = apply_filters( 'wp_new_user_notification_email_admin', $wp_new_user_notification_email_admin, $user, $blogname );
```

... and ...

```
/**
     * Filters the contents of the new user notification email sent to the new user.
     *
     * @since 4.9.0
     *
     * @param array   $wp_new_user_notification_email {
     *     Used to build wp_mail().
     *
     *     @type string $to      The intended recipient - New user email address.
     *     @type string $subject The subject of the email.
     *     @type string $message The body of the email.
     *     @type string $headers The headers of the email.
     * }
     * @param WP_User $user     User object for new user.
     * @param string  $blogname The site title.
     */
    $wp_new_user_notification_email = apply_filters( 'wp_new_user_notification_email', $wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname );
```

The typical filter function code block looks like this...

```
function custom_wp_new_user_notification_email( $wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname ) {
    $wp_new_user_notification_email['subject'] = 'Your Subject';
    $wp_new_user_notification_email['message'] = 'Your Email Message';
    return $wp_new_user_notification_email;
}
```

Inside the `add_filter` functions for these filters, you can get the User specific information using the $user passed to the filter function, like...

```
$user_name = $user->user_login;
$user_email = $user->user_email;
```

Using the $user object, you can get the User information and build your own activation link.

Again, I am not sure if I've followed the motive behind this question correctly; but this is the path I will follow if I'm at this sort of stuff to implement.